# Fitting a region in between two exponentials

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to fit the data for the thermal conductivity of Gallium Arsenide from [[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1714018)]. Although there are theoretical models that explain this phenomenon, they are too complicated for my purposes, so I just want to find an appropriate fitting curve.

[image: fit]

Note the log-log scale of the plot. The blue curve is defined as:
$$f(x)=A\exp(B\ln(x)^2)\exp(C\ln x)$$
I got the above by assuming that it is a quadratic function on a log-log plot. It is not backed up by theory, but works well for me.

The red curve is:
$$g(x) = (D\cdot x\exp(-E/x))^{-1}$$
which is justified by the theory: it shows the exponential behaviour at first and then, for large x, falls as 1/x. It is a very poor fit, to only two data points: the 2nd and 3rd from the right. If I add one more point to the fit though, the plot looks like this:

[image: fit1]

which, in x=150-200 range, is a worse fit than the first one. What could I do to "inflect" the blue curve so it comes closer to the 3rd data point from the right?

Here is the raw data:

```
T       k
3.079   1.399
3.700   2.570
4.470   4.860
6.480   11.47
8.740   19.20
11.06   33.07
18.08   42.24
24.00   40.24
29.20   29.00
40.00   15.73
42.60   13.00
67.40   6.460
95.14   2.970
310.0   0.570
```

Comment: This could be a very stupid comment; so forgive me if it is ! On a log-log scale, the entire curve looks like a distribution function. Could you post the data points ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the data for $24 \leq T \leq 310$ and the model $$y=a\frac{ e^{b/x}}{x}$$ you gave, a quick and dirty nonlinear curve fit leads to $$y=300.453\frac{ e^{28.5042/x}}{x}$$ which does not look too bad (at least to me). The adjusted $R^2=0.997$.

For sure, if you are concerned by high temperatures, it would be better to minimize the sum of squares of relative errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely concerned with the 100-150K region, and the difference between your fit and the data changes my simulations significantly.

Comment: I am afraid that, in this case, you can only use the last three points since you don't have any data for your range of interest. The only other solution I can think about is to use the theoretical model for the whole range. Be sure I am ready to help you (if you wish). Cheers :-)